# Need help setting my default API Route on SwashBuckle (AzureFunctions)

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, azure-functions, swashbuckle

So TL;DR I've been learning how to incorporate shwashbuckle into Azure Functions and It's been working pretty well so far, but I can't change my default route prefix.

I was able to change a number of other properties like title, servers, etc, but I really need the default api to come out as just /path instead of /api/path, if that makes sense.

I'll post my code below and hopefully some of you guys will be able to help me.

Function:

```
namespace SwashBuckleExample.Functions.Functions
{
    public class GetClubByClubNameHttp
    {
        private ISwashBuckleExampleProcess _process;
        private ILogger<GetClubByClubNameHttp> _logger;

        public GetClubByClubNameHttp(ISwashBuckleExampleProcess process, ILogger<GetClubByClubNameHttp> logger)
        {
            _process = process;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Function that runs GetClubByNameProcess
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="req">HttpRequest</param>
        /// <returns>SwashBuckleExampleSuccessResponse Item</returns>
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(SwashBuckleExampleSuccessResponse))]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(SwashBuckleExampleBaseResponse))]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(SwashBuckleExampleBaseResponse))]
        [FunctionName("GetClubByClubNameHttp")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] 
            [RequestBodyType(typeof(SwashBuckleExampleClubNameRequest), "Contains Club Name used for searching purposes")]HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function UpdateClientHttp");

            //Read Query parameters

            //Read RequestBody
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            //Decouple Requests

            SwashBuckleExampleClubNameRequest request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwashBuckleExampleClubNameRequest>(requestBody);

            //Make all pipeline Request
            var responseObject = _process.GetClubByNameProcess(request);
            return !responseObject.HasErrors ? (ObjectResult)new OkObjectResult(responseObject) : (ObjectResult)new BadRequestObjectResult(responseObject);
        }
    }
}
```

SwashBuckleStartup:

```
using System.Reflection;
using AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SwashBuckleExample.Functions;
using SwashBuckleExample.Functions.SwaggerFunctions.SwaggerDocumentFilter;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(SwashBuckleStartup))]
namespace SwashBuckleExample.Functions
{
    internal class SwashBuckleStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            //Register the extension
            builder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), c => 
            {
                c.ConfigureSwaggerGen = (d => d.DocumentFilter<SwashBuckleExampleDocumentFilter>());
            });            
        }
    }
}
```

DocumentFilter:

```
namespace SwashBuckleExample.Functions.SwaggerFunctions.SwaggerDocumentFilter
{
    public class SwashBuckleExampleDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            swaggerDoc.Info.Title = "SwashBuckleExample";
            swaggerDoc.Info.Version = "v1";
            swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>() { new OpenApiServer() { Url = "LinkToServer" } };
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

ps:

I need to remove this parameter that always shows up and I don't know why. Is there any way to do so?
[Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KFab.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***1. How to change Azure function default route prefix.***

If we want to change Azure function default route prefix, we can implement it by setting **routePrefix** specified in the **host.json**. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/routes?tabs=csharp) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-output#hostjson-settings).
[image]

For example

Add the following settings in your `host.json` file.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {

    "http": {
      "routePrefix" : ""
    }
  },
  ....
}
```

[image]

> ***2. Why does your swagger file have query parameter `code`?***

The reason for this situation is that you set the Azure function HTTP trigger auth level as **Function** or **Admin** with code `HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]`. After doing that, we need to provide the function key or host key to be included in a query string variable named `code` when we call the function. Its URL should be like`https://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>?code=<API_KEY>`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#api-key-authorization)

For example

My code

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(TestModel[]), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [FunctionName("TestGets")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Gets([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "test")]
            HttpRequest request)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(new[] { new TestModel(), new TestModel() });
        }

        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TestModel), (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
        [FunctionName("TestAdd")]
        public Task<IActionResult> Add([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "test")]
            TestModel testModel)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(new CreatedResult("", testModel));
        }
```

[image]

So if you want to remove the parameter, please update code as `[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,...)`

For example
My code

```
ProducesResponseType(typeof(TestModel), (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
        [FunctionName("TestAdd")]
        public Task<IActionResult> Add([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "test")]
            TestModel testModel)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(new CreatedResult("", testModel));
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to remove the parameter without AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous?

We usually upload our functions to a FunctionApp and call it via Azure Api Management, and keeping that code is a good safety measure, I just don't want it to show on swagger.